WixToolset v4 util:XmlFile NLog.config Element XPath ElementPath and its Value
I would like to edit the NLogConfig file with MSI Installation using WiX Toolset v4.
Using the util:XmlFile from WiX Toolset. I get an error message at compliation:
"ICE03: Invalid format string; Table:Wix4XmlFile, Column:ElementPath, Key(s): editNLogConfig".
I have tried this:
This is the ElementPath:
your textElementPath="/nlog/targets/target[1]/@fileName".
I have 3 Properties: ENVIMPORTDIR, IMPPART1 and IMPPART2 their values are supplied by the user via the cmd line and are to be substituted here in the (replacement) Value:
your textValue="${[ENVIMPORTDIR]}[IMPPART1] layout=[IMPPART2]"
your textENVIMPORTDIR = "\ttt-filer.tt.yy\sdf\uer\qar\sdf2"
your textIMPPART1" =" MyApp_WinServ_Central\MyApp\system\logs\MyApp_WinServ_${shortdate}.log"
your textIMPPART2 Value="${longdate} ${uppercase:${level}} ${message}" />
I have used an online XPath Tester to verify the syntax and the above was OK there.
Can somebody tell me why I get the error ICE03? Can anybody see what is wrong with the values for the Attributes: ElementPath and/or Value?
Any help is very appriciated
here is the NLog.config:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd NLog.xsd" autoReload="true" throwExceptions="false" internalLogLevel="Off" internalLogFile="c:\temp\nlog-internal.log">
  
<variable name="logDirectory" value"\\abc-filer.abc.xxx\\efg\\hij\\klm\\sdf1"></variable>
  
  <targets>
    <target xsi:type="File" 
    name="logfile" 
    fileName="${logDirectory}/MyApp_WinServ_Central/MyApp/system/logs/MyApp_WinServ_${shortdate}.log" layout="${longdate} ${uppercase:${level}} ${message}"/>    
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="logfile" /> 
  </rules>
</nlog>

I want to replace the xml variable: logDirectory at WiX Installation using the WiX Property and the util:XmlFile functionality by providing the ElementPath and Value.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

here is the NLog.config File:
